# java loop does not increase array index

Tags: java

let's say I have an integer array `int[] A = {0, 1, 2, 0}`
the main method is

```
int i = 0, a = A[i], b = A[i + 1];

while(i < 3) {
  System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + i);
  i++;
}
```

why does the console outputs

```
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 1 2
```

even though the index is already pass 0 where I expected `a` to be 1 and `b` to be 2

Comment: There's nothing in the loop which changes `a` or `b`; why do you expect those to change?

Comment: a=A[i] assigns the value of A[i] to a. After that a holds that number, and it does not change when i changes (so A[i] changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this line of code executes, these are the (simplified) states of each variable in existence at the time.

```
int i = 0, a = A[i], b = A[i + 1]
---------------------
| A  | {0, 1, 2, 0} |
| i  |  0           |
| a  |  0           |
| b  |  1           |
---------------------
```

Notice that `a` and `b` are simply numbers, not any sort of reference to array `A` dependent on the value of `i`.

When you move down to `i++;`, the only change to the variables above is `| i | 1 |`

If you'd like to update `a` and `b` within your loop, you'll need to access the values in array A based on the updated index. Part of your print statement might look like `System.out.println(A[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```java
int i = 0, a = 0, b = 0;
while(i < 3){
    a = A[i];
    b = b[++i];
    System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + i);
}
```